# How to compile .asy files under Windows 10

Tags: asymptote

I am a complete beginner in terms of vectorial graphics. In my Bachelor Thesis I get data (provided in the attached file), which I want to compile with the programm Asymptote. I know, that it is possible to configure my TexStudio in a way, that it compiles .asy files. 
But my supervisor don't want me to do it like that. I already downloaded the programm Asymptote and got the file. However I am not able to compile it under Windows 10. I think im just doing a stupid mistake in terms of syntax, because my Supervisor can compile the provided file under Ubuntu with Asymptote.

Now my question:
Can someone give me a detailed "command" path to how I can compile the file?

I already tried the following:

1. start Asymptote
2. change the directory to the folder where "plots.asy" is
3. file fin=input("plots.asy")
   and then I get an error 1.1 "Cannot open file "plots.asy".

So I also already tried to use my Windows shell and compile it with this in the following way:

1. Start the Windows shell
2. change the directory to the folder with "plots.asy"
3. type: `asy.exe -f .png` "plots.asy" and run it.
   then I get the following error:

   > plots.asy: 1.13: cannot call 'guide operator --(... guide[])' with parameters
   >   '(triple, triple)'
   >   plots.asy: 1.49: no matching variable 'Arrow3'

I already tried to solve my problem by reading the manual provided by Asymptote itself, but i just can't figure it out. I already searched this forum and some other tutorials, but I only found either the manual or the problem is not the same as mine.

And last but not least the [file](http://www.file-upload.net/download-12203707/plots.asy.html). It's uploaded on fileupload.net, I hope this is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Put

```
import three;
```

before the first line of the file.

Comment: Ok, with this i get it to load with the windows shell way, however i get an "out of memory" error then. I looked it up and my task manager shows, that not even 20% of my RAM is used. Everything else is also normal. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: On my MacOS system your file with that line added compiles without problems. But it seems that "out of memory happens more on Windows. Google "asymptote out of memory".